# Can I tweak the Android Navigation codebase so that I can track multiple gps devices on my android?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I want to add a feature to the android navigation system, such that I can track my friend's
android device as well as mine, simultaneously in real time on the google navigation map.

Is there any google navigation api available to do so or should I work at the source code level?
If it is the latter, where can I get the source code?

Thanks,
Yashoteja

Comment: you can find the source code using google

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is anything like an API in the Google Navigation.

But what you can do is to use the [Maps API](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html) in your application and then display the position or your device and your friends.

You will need to take care of getting the data from your friends GPS all the way to your device... that's probably where most of your work is.

The source code you will need to work on is your own application's.